# One tap triggering events on multiple views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uibutton

In my program I have placed a `UIButton` as a subview of a `UIView`, both of which have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `true`. When the button is tapped, an event is called to handle the button tap, which works as expected. However, the button's `UIView` superview also handles an event which should not be triggered in this case. Can anybody explain why the `UIButton` AND `UIView` are both triggering an event? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please add some more code.UIView triggering touchesBegan or any other action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution: I simply made the button a superview of the view which was handling unwanted events, rather than a subview.

Answer (score 0):

Should you resign first responder after the button has done its duty so that the view that the button is in is no longer in control.

How about adding: **bringSubviewtoFront:scrollview**

to the end of your UIButton code. The idea here is to make your uiview the foremost view; which is what I think is happening when you touch the uiview and thus reactivating the triggering events